Show that $k[X,Y,T]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1),XT-Y,T^2-X+1)\simeq k[T]$, where $T=Y/X$.
The question arises from reading the answer here. $k$ here is a field.
The proof reads, "But $k[X,Y,T]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1),XT-Y,T^2-X+1)\simeq k[T]$, and thus we get two things..."
My Question: I can't quite see why the two sides above are isomorphic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

We have the following chain of isomorphisms:
\begin{align*}
k[X,Y,T]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1),XT-Y,T^2-X+1)
&\cong k[T^2+1,Y,T]/(Y^2-(T^2+1)^2T^2,(T^2+1)T-Y),\text{ imposed by the element $T^2-X+1$}\\
&=k[Y,T]/(Y^2-(T^2+1)T^2,(T^2+1)T-Y)\\
&\cong k[(T^2+1)T,T]/((T^2+1)^2T^2-(T^2+1)^2T^2),\text{ imposed by the element $(T^2+1)T-Y$}\\
&=k[T]/(0)\\
&\cong k[T]
\end{align*}
